# How to save and read Latin1 charecters in java properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

I am trying to save Latin1 character "ÀßÖ" in test.properties file.
But it storing like "\u00C0\u00DF\u00D6". But i am expecting store exact values.
Any help as possible.

Comment: Those are the exact Unicode values, as required by the standard for property files.

Comment: is it possible to save "ÀßÖ" in properties file instead of "\u00C0\u00DF\u00D6"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store using a *Writer* using the overloaded [store(Writer,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) method but you should not.

The standard way to save/load is via an OutputStream/InputStream. Documentation for [store(OutputStream,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29):

> This method outputs the comments, properties keys and values in the
> same format as specified in `store(Writer)`, with the following
> differences:
>
> - The stream is written using the ISO 8859-1 character encoding.
> - Characters not in Latin-1 in the comments are written as \uxxxx for their appropriate unicode hexadecimal value xxxx.
> - Characters less than \u0020 and characters greater than \u007E in property keys or values are written as \uxxxx for the appropriate
>   hexadecimal value xxxx.

If you write data using another mechanism then any application expecting the standard form will fail as this code demonstrates:

```
Path file = Paths.get("tmp.properties");
Properties write = new Properties();
write.put("key", "\u00C0\u00DF\u00D6");
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  write.store(writer, "demo");
}
Properties read = new Properties();
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
  read.load(in);
}
if (!write.get("key").equals(read.get("key"))) {
  throw new IOException("expected: " + write.get("key") + "; got: "
      + read.get("key"));
}
```

If the escaping is problematic, consider using an alternative format such as JSON - [JSON mandates Unicode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3).

Comment: Hi i am using jdk1.5 your code will work for jdk1.7 any solution using jdk1.5 plz
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  write.store(writer, "demo");
}
is not supporting in jdk 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 1.6 can solve using below code:

```
Writer writer = null;
    try
    {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;

        output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test1.properties");
        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("database", "ÀßÖ");
        prop.setProperty("dbuser", "ÀßÖ");
        prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "ÀßÖ");

        // writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "windows-1252");
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
        // writer.append("Text");
        prop.store(writer, null);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    }

    finally
    {

        try
        {
            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Try let me know.

Comment: I need the solution for jdk1.5